# Removing duplicate values within a comma separated list in PHP

Tags: php, string, duplicates, concatenation

How can I remove duplicate values within a comma separated list in PHP?

I have 2 versions of a customer questionnaire - one is more detailed than the other - and in one they are asked the items they like and in the other they are asked to specify the items they like in ranked order. In this particular example, one of the columns ('items_like') may contain several values in a comma separated list. There are two other scenarios where each of the columns may contain several values in a comma separated list.

In order to display a list of all the items a customer likes, I am concatenating the 4 columns when the information is fetched from the db. How can I remove any duplicate values from the combined comma separated list in? I'd prefer doing this in PHP than Javascript

```
try {  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id"); 
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$search = array('_', ',', 'Null');
$replace = array(' ', ', ', '');
$rows = str_replace($search, $replace, $row);

$merged_likes = $rows['items_like']. ",  " . $rows['first_like']. ",  " .     $rows['second_like']. ",  " .  $rows['third_like'];
echo $merged_likes;
```

Comment: `explode`, `array_unique`, `implode`.

Comment: Isn't SELECT DISTINCT an option?

Comment: I second @Gumbo and would like to add that this sounds like a bad DB design - having multiple comma separated values in one column.

Comment: @pce - these are in the same row in the db (since they're the same customer), so I don't think that Select Distinct would work here

Comment: @Gumbo - Can you show me an example of how to use it?

Comment: `implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $array)))`

Comment: @Havelock - I'm curious why it would be a bad idea to have multiple comma separated values in one column for form elements with multiple values selected (multiselects and checkboxes)?

Comment: @ChayaCooper, have a look at the article [Database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), it may help you to see whether I'm right or wrong.

Comment: @Gumbo - I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work :-( Would you mind showing me how to use it with my code? I've tried several things, including $new_var = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $merged_likes)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with lists of things, it's easiest to use [arrays](http://php.net/arrays). Comma-separated strings work alright for displaying things, but they're no fun to work with in code. With that in mind, I would recommend not even touching a comma until you finally display the data out to the screen.

Unfortunately, it sounds like you already have comma separated strings stored in your database. If this is something you can change, you may want to look into an alternative database structure using multiple tables with a one-to-many relationship between users and things they like. There's a lot that could be said about this, but it's not the subject of your question. The basic concept is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), as Havelock has already mentioned.

In the event the database structure cannot be changed and you must work the comma-separated lists, simply undo the comma separation and get them back into arrays in PHP. To do this, you'd use the [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) function:

```
$teststring = '1,2,3';
$test = explode(',', $asdfstring); // array(1, 2, 3)
```

Once you have arrays, PHP has some handy features for sorting, removing duplicates, etc. The one you're probably most interested in here is [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique).

To put it back into a comma-separated list for display, simply use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), which does the opposite of `explode()` by taking an array and joining it with the separator of your choice (e.g., comma).

Now since you have multiple columns you're dealing with here, and you only want one list, you're going to have to build the array in multiple steps. If every one of these columns can contain multiple values, you can do the explosion thing on all of them:

```
$items_like = explode(',', $rows['items_like']);
$first_like = explode(',', $rows['first_like']);
$second_like = explode(',', $rows['second_like']);
$third_like = explode(',', $rows['third_like']);
$merged = array_merge($items_like, $first_like, $second_like, $third_like);
```

Or if first, second, and third will only contain one item, you could do this:

```
$items_like = explode(',', $rows['items_like']);
$other_likes = array($rows['first_like'], $rows['second_like'], $rows['third_like']);
$merged = array_merge($items_like, $other_likes);
```

Now remove duplicates:

```
$likes = array_unique($merged);
```

Now we're finally ready to add commas:

```
echo implode(', ', $likes);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation :-) It looks like this code is only removing duplicates when all the values in a column are exactly the same (when the columns have only value and it's identical value or several values and they're all identical), but it's not working when only one of the values is duplicated :-(

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be working for me. To debug it, try running `var_dump($likes);`. This should show you each individual element in the array. There shouldn't be any duplicates. If items are different because of case or whitespace, though, that could be an issue.

Comment: I got duplicates when I ran the var_dump($likes) too :-( The result was 'array(5) { [0]=> string(9) "Chocolate" [1]=> string(5) " Wine" [2]=> string(6) "Cheese" [3]=> string(5) "Fruit" [4]=> string(4) "Wine" }'

Comment: The two wine entries are different: one is a five-character string, and one is a four-character string. Note the space in front of the first one: `" Wine"`. To deal with whitespace issues, use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim). You can trim your whitespace before putting it in the database or after. If you wanted to deal with it in this code, you could use `$likes = array_map('trim', array_unique($merged));`.

Comment: Alternatively, if the items in the comma-separated list are always separated by a comma and a space, use `explode(', ', $string)` instead of `explode(',', $string)`.

Comment: I totally missed that :-) I was actually adding the space in the str_replace function for $rows ;-) Explode(', ', $string) fixed the problem :-D I'm assuming that's probably the better way to go here?

Comment: I completely overlooked that. Another option would be to remove the replacement of `','` with `', '`. It doesn't make too much difference, though. The cleanest solution would be one that doesn't have comma-delimited strings in the database, but again, that's a larger issue.