# Removing unnecessary commas when concatenating variables into a comma separated list?

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

When I concatenate PHP variables to form a comma separated list it adds a comma regardless of whether or not that variable has a value.

How can I remove the unnecessary commas when concatenating variables into a comma separated list?

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$search = array('_', ',', 'Null');
$replace = array(' ', ', ', '');
$rows = str_replace($search, $replace, $row);

$merged_likes = $rows['items_like'] . ",  " . $rows['first_like'] . ",  " . $rows['second_like'] . ",  " . $rows['third_like'];
echo $merged_likes;
```

Comment: Isn't this trivial? Loop over all the "variables" and check if they're empty before adding them to the final result.

Comment: @DCoder - That's an interesting idea. I know that I could do that in order to add each one separately (using .= instead of a single = to concatenate new data onto the end of the variable), but that still results in an extra comma at the beginning when the 1rst value is empty. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15045882/1411510). Once you have the items in an array, just filter out anything that's blank with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter). Example:

```
$likes = array_filter($likes, function($item)
{
    return !empty($item);
});

echo implode(', ', $likes);
```

This syntax will only work with PHP >=5.3.0. See [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for more information.

#### Edit

As KingCrunch mentions below, if all of your blank items [evaluate to `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (e.g., an empty string), you can simply omit the callback function:

```
$likes = array_filter($likes);
echo implode(', ', $likes);

// or more succinctly

echo implode(', ', array_filter($likes));
```

Comment: Addition: You don't need a callback, when the items you want to filter out evaluates to `false`: `$likes = array_filter($likes);`.

Comment: I never knew that. Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and it works perfectly even when I don't need to need to worry about duplicate values :-D Thank you so much!