# Delete duplicated tags MySQL

Tags: mysql, tags

I have duplicated tags on my MySQL DB such as below:

```
| id  | tags                                |
+- ---+-------------------------------------+
| 3   | x,yz,z,x,x                          |
| 5   | a,b,c d,a,b,c d, d                  |
+-----+-------------------------------------+
```

How can I execute a query that can remove the duplicated tags?

The result should be:

```
| id  | tags                                |
+- ---+-------------------------------------+
| 3   | x,yz,z                              |
| 5   | a,b,c d, d                          |
+-----+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: first normalise your data

Comment: @amdixon This is not an option, as I can not change the schema.

Answer (score 3):

**setup**

```
create table overly_complex_tags
(
  id integer primary key not null,
  tags varchar(100) not null
);

insert into overly_complex_tags
( id, tags )
values
( 3   , 'x,yz,z,x,x'           ),
( 5   , 'a,b,c d,a,b,c d,d'    )
;

create view digits_v
as
SELECT 0 AS N 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 8 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 9
;
```

**query delete duplicate tags**

```
update overly_complex_tags t
inner join
(
select id, group_concat(tag) as new_tags
from
(
select distinct t.id, substring_index(substring_index(t.tags, ',', n.n), ',', -1) tag
from overly_complex_tags t 
cross join
(
  select a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
  from digits_v a
  cross join digits_v b
  order by n
) n
where n.n <= 1 + (length(t.tags) - length(replace(t.tags, ',', '')))
) cleaned_tags
group by id
) updated_tags
on t.id = updated_tags.id
set t.tags = updated_tags.new_tags
;
```

**output**

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   tags    |
+----+-----------+
|  3 | yz,z,x    |
|  5 | c d,a,d,b |
+----+-----------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33e0c6/2)**

---

**note**

> the complexity of above solution comes from not having a properly
>   normalised structure.. note that the solution uses an intermediate
>   normalised structure

Comment: not sure what is more zanny. The question or this :P

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle we accomplish this as

```
Update table set col=(select distinct regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level) col
          from table)
```

But for MySQL it not possible and only way is through PHP array as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044672/removing-duplicate-values-within-a-comma-separated-list-in-php). However Maria db have its solution as well. So use intermediate way.