# determine a database relationship

Tags: mysql

I need help to decide if the relationship between this 2 table is one to many or many to many. One student can sign up for many class and one class can have multiple student. This is my table below:

[image]

Thankyou

Comment: Normalize your structures first. Holding `class_student_id` as csv list is a bad idea. Use **[Junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)** instead(**[example](http://www.thinkingcog.com/image.axd?picture=clip_image002_thumb.gif)**)

Comment: see **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553775/mysql-select-query-to-fetch-record-base-on-list-values/34553991#34553991)** for how to fix your structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be:

[image: DB Diagram]

classes to students is in HABTM Relationship maped by classes_students. 
Below is schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `classes` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `classes_students` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `class_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `student_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK__classes` (`class_id`),
    INDEX `FK__students` (`student_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__classes` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `classes` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__students` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `students` (`id`)
)
COMMENT='table to support HABT classes to students'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: How do I add a student into a class? Should I insert a new record to class table then I can add a student into class_student table? Or is there other way . Sorry, I'm really new to junction table !'

Comment: just create a new entry in classes_students with student_id and class_id where you want the put the students to. this is all. to remove a student from a class you just have to find and delete record from classes_students table only.

first create a class(if not exists) and then student(again if not exist) and then add entry to classes_students.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)). You need to have Students and Classes into separate tables and connect them via a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) which will contain a student_id and a class_id.

Comment: What if a class have other fields such as teacher , subject , do I add them into junction table or class table

Comment: If you need to have teachers in your system you should create a table which holds the teachers. Then you connect the teacher to the class depending on their relationship (one or many teachers per class). For the subjects, if you just need a title you can put it in the class as a field, but if you need a complete subjects with more info, you need to create a table for them.